# PHP IF stops IE content from loading

Tags: php

**scenario** 
I have a PHP if statement to test if a user is logging in for the first time ever. This then displays, a demo in a greybox popup box.

Sadly when the box loads in IE, the content of the website doesn't. This means when I user closes the box, they are left the with background.

**Code** - I'm now using PHP include.

*greybox.php*

```
<?php if ($fli == 0) {echo " <script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() {
 GB_showCenter('Your first login', '../video.php');
};
</script> ";} else echo "";?>



<!-- GB scrip --> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var GB_ROOT_DIR = "greybox/";
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<link href="greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- GB -->
```

*RELEVANT Script on main site*

```
<?php  $fli = $_SESSION["USER"]["fli"]; ?>
<?php include "greybox.php" ?>
```

[image: Comparison of IE / Chrome]

I would deeply appreicate any help at all please! :)

Comment: Is the `<script>` not output to the browser or does the Javascript simply not work? Narrow the problem down. Also: `else echo "";` can be replaced with: , i.e. you don't need it.

Comment: Try echoing off `$fli` and `$_SESSION["USER']["fli"]` to see what their values are. They may not be setting properly and causing an error that is stopping execution of your script.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem then?

Comment: @deceze the problem is when on IE the actual web content (the things that look like blocks [screenshot]) don't load. So when you do click off to close the video, you're left with the background only and nothing else. Chrome there's no issue.

Comment: So the actual problem is completely unrelated to your question in its current form?

Comment: Oh balls! I was having issues composing this question, and it seems I missed some info on the question

Comment: Is that javascript output in the middle of the page? Maybe try moving the output of the script to the end of the page.

Comment: @MikeBrant if I have the code lower then the main content wont load on Chrome too

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with it but what if you try the full url for a test.
How does IE then reacts?

Alternative could be [jQueryIU](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), you can create a dialog for the first login.
Also if I restart my browser do I have to see the video again?
If you save the last login in the DB you can use that information to show the video.

Good luck.

Comment: When you restart the browser no, you will never see it again. The problem is the main website content doesn't load on IE, it only loads the box.. I'll look into jQ'IU